# Retrieving real and imaginary part of complex numbers stored as strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I've done this to recover the first part of the string, for example: the "13" of "13+i":

```
l1 = ['13+i', '1+4i', '3+2i', '11+4i', '5+i', '10+2i', '5+4i']
l2 = [i.split('+')[0] for i in l1]
l2 = list(map(int, l2))
```

It worked well and then I want the "1" from "13+i" but it is more complicated ever since the "i" in the string got no "1" factor.

I should get:

```
[1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4]
```

i.e., only the imaginary part of the complex number in an array.

Any idea to help me solve this?

Comment: so for 1+4i and 3+2i you want 1 and 3 respectively? Also can you clarify the last sentence `the "i" in the string got no "1" factor`

Comment: It looks like you're working with complex numbers. Python can do this normally, there's a type for it. You can then easily recover the imaginary and real parts. See [the docs](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/complex/).

Comment: No in 1+4i and 3+2i  i want 4 and 2

Comment: Actually my list is made of strings so i considered like i cant use python3 math lib

Comment: What if you have `12-3i` or just `4i`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has a way of dealing with complex numbers; it actually has a type for them (`<class 'complex'>`). As a result, and to avoid having to *re-invent the wheel* I would strongly recommend using that.

To do that, we must first *sanitise* our input (convert the values from `strings` to `complex`). To do that we must first adhere to Python's conventions for the *imaginary unit* for which `'j'` is used and not `'i'`.

```
l1 = ['13+i', '1+4i', '3+2i', '11+4i', '5+i', '10+2i', '5+4i']
l1 = [complex(x.replace('i', 'j')) for x in l1]

# if you are curious how they look like
print(l1)
# -> [(13+1j), (1+4j), ...]
```

With the values now in a proper format, we can take advantage of the [`.real` and `.imag` attributes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cmath.html#conversions-to-and-from-polar-coordinates) of variables of type `complex` and built our result lists using list-compehensions.

```
real_parts = [value.real for value in l1]
print(real_parts) 
# -> [13.0, 1.0, 3.0, 11.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0]

imaginary_parts = [value.imag for value in l1]
print(imaginary_parts)
# -> [1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

Note that by default, they are all real numbers (real as in not-integer). Casting them to `int` could easily be achieved with `[int(value.real) for value in l1]`.

Probably the nicest thing about using existing functionality is that you **do not have to worry** about edge cases which you might have not though possible and as a result might have caused your code to break. For instance `4j` (no real part) or `1-j` (negative imaginary part so `.split('+')[0]` would not work) and so on.

Comment: Nitpick: `.real` and `.imag` are not methods, are they? "Members", perhaps? Apart from that exactly what I'd have done.

Comment: @tobias_k Would you call them *attributes*? Or *properties*? Feel free to edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

The python complex type uses j instead of i to denote complex numbers.

Thus,

```
i=['13+i','1+4i','3+2i','11+4i','5+i','10+2i','5+4i']
real_parts=[ complex(x.replace("i", "j")).real for x in i]
imaginary_parts=[ complex(x.replace("i", "j")).imag for x in i ]
```

Would be what you're looking for.